# How to get a div element to have the same background-image as its parent?

Tags: html, css

How do i get the child div element to have the same background texture as the parent element? The background is a texture of small squares, however when I try give the child element the same background as the parent element the squares don't line up. Any ideas?

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.parent{
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  background-image:url('wallpaper324845.jpg')
}
.child{
width:200px;
height:200px;  
/*how to get the same background-image*/
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">

  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't assign the child a background.

Comment: this - by default, a div has no background and is transparent so the parent background would come through.

Comment: Oh thanx, can't believe i missed that. 4 minutes until i can tick the answer xD

Answer (score 2):

would `background-image: inherit;` do it?

or `background: transparent;` ?

Comment: no, the backgrounds are offset i.e. they don't line up

Comment: Heres a pen showing this work (I only tested in Opera 12) http://codepen.io/anon/pen/klfhj

Comment: @user3247608 This is the answer to your question, but the other one (by @RyneEverett) is probably the answer to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: if you want additional properties from the parent element you can use `inherit` on most of them; or even `background: inherit`. (Just more codepen.io tinkers: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/klfhj)